# Bosonization for unequal left/right Fermi velocities

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin, bosonization

The standard exposition of bosonization/Luttinger liquid theory in textbooks treats the case that left and right channels share the same absolute value of Fermi velocity. Is it possible to relax this equal-velocity constraint in bosonization? At first sight, it may be not straightforward. I can't find anything alike in the literature.
Let's say we have only one species of spinless Fermion. So I mean the simplest case rather than the situation (e.g. two coupled chains) when there are two species with certainly different velocities.

Comment: You should just bosonizing the chiral fermions in terms of chiral bosons, say $\psi_R \sim e^{i\phi_R}, \psi_L \sim e^{i\phi_L}$, then the Hamiltonian looks like $v_R (\partial_x\phi_R)^2 + v_L (\partial_x\phi_L)^2$.

Comment: @MengCheng Thank you a lot for your nice information. Never heard of it before. Shame... So this kind of bosonization can also handle interactions? Is it the common practice as to my question? Could you please provide some reference for learning such method?

Comment: This is the standard bosonization of 1D fermions, so any serious introduction to bosonization should basically start from here. For example, Sec II of http://www.physics.upenn.edu/~kane/pedagogical/boulderlec12.pdf. A more comprehensive reference is Giamarchi's book "Quantum physics in one dimension".

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to have different velocities for the different channels. For example, in the case of a coupled quantum Hall edge in quantum Hall effect, nothing prevents the edges from having different velocities. Velocity is determined the slope of the confinement potential. This [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0201016) presents the results of what happens when the edges have different dispersion relation. Hope this is what you were looking for.